# jQuery: I'm trying to bind a click action to multiple elements with the same class

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".slider_link").each(function(i, elem){
        elem.click(function(){
            $("div#"+elem.attr("tag")).slideUp(300);
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

but after the first one (checked with alert) it breaks saying index.html has no method click... whats up with that?

html:

```
        <li><a href="#" tag="home" class="slider_link">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" tag="calendar" class="slider_link">Calendar</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" tag="officers" class="slider_link">Officers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" tag="media" class="slider_link">Media</a></li>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `elem` is the current DOM element, not a jQuery object which has the [`.click()` method](http://api.jquery.com/click/), you either to wrap it in a jQuery object using `$()` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".slider_link").each(function(i, elem){
        $(elem).click(function(){
            $("div#"+$(elem).attr("tag")).slideUp(300);
        });
    });
});
```

Or even shorter just bind all of them the same and get the attribute when any one is clicked:

```
$(function() {
  $(".slider_link").click(function(){
    $("#"+$(this).attr("tag")).slideUp(300);
  });
});
```

---

An even better solution would be to make this simpler and work with JS disabled, change your markup like this:

```
 <li><a href="#home" class="slider_link">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#calendar" class="slider_link">Calendar</a></li>
 <li><a href="#officers" class="slider_link">Officers</a></li>
 <li><a href="#media" class="slider_link">Media</a></li>
```

Then you can bind your `click` handler like this:

```
$(function() {
  $(".slider_link").click(function(e){
    $(this.hash).slideUp(300);
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent page scroll
  });
});
```

This works even if JS is disabled, it'll just scroll the page to the `<div id="home">`, etc when you click the corresponding link.